# How to use blocking.cv

Tags: partitioning, cross-validation, mlr, blockingcollection

When i try to run the following code

```
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV", blocking.cv = TRUE,iters=5L,folds=10)
```

i take this error

Error in makeResampleDescCV(blocking.cv = TRUE, iters = 5L, folds = 10) : 
  unused arguments (blocking.cv = TRUE, folds = 10)

Answer (score 0):

`blocking.cv` is a new argument that isn't in the latest released version of mlr yet. You'll need to use the development version from github to use it. See the [tutorial](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/index.html#install-the-development-version) for instructions.

Further, `iters` and `folds` describe the same thing here, so only specify one of them.